# Invocation function in global js object Function

Tags: javascript

i have a small/big problem. Now I need a functionality of that tip - when i invoke any function I want stopped it in debugger.

I am find  solution

```
Function.prototype.debug = function(){   
   var fn = this; 
   return function(){     
       if (debugme) debugger; 
       return fn.apply(this, arguments);     
   }; 
};
```

But in that case reaaly need do something like this foo.debug();

But there is about 200 functions.

So, there is no solution) I really have answer can I do it. Or can I invoke function in global function object constructor.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.whitefrost.com/projects/funmon/api/FunMon2.html#FunctionMonitorexampleindex